# Export remote XML DB files and store in SQLite DB to use by android app

Tags: android, mysql, xml, sqlite

I have access to a set of remote XML files stored in a server (XML files of a MySql database tables).
I have to import and create my own SQLite BD to use them with the android mobile app. When remote XML files update(When MySql database information change), the SQLite DB also Should change accordingly.

Can any one guide me how to accomplish this task this.

Sample coding/ reference/ Idea highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Download and Parse the XML files
2.Store them in SQLite database
3.Write a background scheduled service which executes the code for corresponding the above 1 and 2.
Or 
Use the Cloud to Device message from your server to the android app to update your SQLite  database(but I thought the above 1 and 2 points may need here also.It is all about your logic how you develop the application).

Comment: Do you have any idea or mechanism to update the SQLite database when the remote XML files (XML files of a MySql database tables) get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my xsl template
http://code.google.com/p/mysql2sqlite-xslt/.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :-) Although we like references in our answers, we'd like our answers to be "standalone". Please explain/summarize why the referenced webpage answers the question